# Get list of image paths from one open list and paste them into XML template using Notepad++

Tags: xml, notepad++

I have a random list of URL image links:

```
image1: images/DecWhiteGlitter29121305.jpg
image2: images/DecWhiteGlitter29121302.jpg
image3: images/DecWhiteGlitter29121306.jpg
image4: images/DecWhiteGlitter29121399.jpg
image5: images/DecWhiteGlitter29121301.jpg
image6: images/DecWhiteGlitter29121307.jpg
...
```

I need to insert them in a newsletter XML template which looks [like this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8182569). Image1 should go to the first image link, image 2 second image link, etc:

```
<img class="aligncenter" alt="" src="link of image1" width="720" />
.....
<img class="aligncenter" alt="" src="link of image2" width="720" />
```

Ideally, it should get the first image path and paste it to the first URL image link in the XML template, and after go to the second image path and paste it to the second URL image link, etc...

I don't know if this is something that can be done automatically using a macro for example?

Comment: Does your original XML had some sort of mapping for images? Like in you example, src="link of image1". If so then I think I've a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make it immediately obvious as to how automated you want this. But it seems like your linked example xml file has a lot of obvious repetition. This repetition needs to happen per item in your source list of images and their paths.

You can't just create the xml with a pre-made list of "places" to put the source list of images into. That's going about it the wrong way. Either use a proper templating language, or use the solution below and customize it as you see fit.

1. Do ctrl+f in notepad to open up the find and replace window tab.
2. Tick the radio option "Regular Expression"
3. Input the following expression into the "Find what" textbox:

   (\w+):\s+(.*)
4. In your "Replace with" text box, put the following:

   `<img class="aligncenter" alt="\1" src="\2" width="720" />`

The end result with you

```
<img class="aligncenter" alt="image1" src="images/DecWhiteGlitter29121305.jpg" width="720" />
<img class="aligncenter" alt="image2" src="images/DecWhiteGlitter29121302.jpg" width="720" />
<img class="aligncenter" alt="image3" src="images/DecWhiteGlitter29121306.jpg" width="720" />
<img class="aligncenter" alt="image4" src="images/DecWhiteGlitter29121399.jpg" width="720" />
<img class="aligncenter" alt="image5" src="images/DecWhiteGlitter29121301.jpg" width="720" />
<img class="aligncenter" alt="image6" src="images/DecWhiteGlitter29121307.jpg" width="720" />
```